# fancybox YouTube link not working at all

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I get no console errors whatsoever. Here is the code I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/punx/wordpress/wp-content/themes/bone-theme/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/punx/wordpress/wp-content/themes/bone-theme/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        helpers : {
            media : {}
        }
    });
});
</script>       

<div class="video-item">

    <a class="fancybox-media" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E34eBjaqmgo&feature=youtube_gdata_player">
    <img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/E34eBjaqmgo/0.jpg" alt="" />
    <span>Video Title Here</span>
    </a>

</div>
```

The link simply takes me directly to YouTube. Like I said, I get no console errors.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to link the `jquery.fancybox-media.js` file, which would allow you to use the `media` helper. Tested your code with the helper added and it worked just fine.

Comment: Figured this out, but thank you, this is the correct answer to the problem.